# Maximal Element vs Greatest Element

Tags: order-theory

*Disclaimer: This thread is written in Q&A style. The answer is provided below.*

Let $A$ be a poset.

If $a$ is a greatest element then $a$ is a unique maximal element.

Is the converse true as well?

Comment: As with all questions of this nature (in which you are answering yourself), add the fact that you are answering this question within your question statement so that people do not try to close the question on the grounds of having not shown work.

Comment: @Hayden: Yes got it thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No since still there can be incomparable elements for a unique maximal element.

Consider for example the disjoint union $\mathbb{R}\sqcup [0,1]$ with the partial order $a\leq b$ for $\pi(a)=\pi(b)$. Then $1$ is the only maximal element but it is not a greatest element.

[image]

Comment: Did you just answer yourself?

Comment: Yepp ;) I did that for my notes

Comment: @DanielCharry It's an acceptable practice.

Comment: Yes i just read about a badge for answering a question asked by oneself.

Comment: @Git Gud: it *can* be acceptable under some circumstances, but this sort of question and answer is better put on a personal website.

Comment: @CarlMummert I should have been clearer, I thought about mentioning this, but I decided not to. Maybe I should have. I mean that it is accepted with respect to the [official policy](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). To be honest, in practice I've never seen the community accept self answers well.

Comment: So what is the purpose of SE? I don't think it is to provide only solutions to theorems on a level of a thesis but to precisely clarify little problems that might hook people... @amWhy, azimut, Carl and others: This starts getting ridiculous. You're involved in almost every closing... I'm full of it now. Keep on doing so - I don't care anymore. But let me just mention my personal opinion: You're spoiling SE!